# How to quickly aggregate large amount of data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to aggregate all the keywords in the news for a period of time, for example:

```
{
  "news_ID":"123456",
  "news_content":"Apple pencil",
  "keywords": {
      [
        {
         "word" : "Apple",
         "score" : 0.0653220043
        },
        {
         "word" : "pencil",
         "score" : 0.7096893191
        }
      ]
    },
  "publish_time":"2020-01-03"
}
```

I want to know how many times `apple` appeared between 2020-01 and 2020-02, but there are too many keywords...

Could you please advise me on how I should approach this requirement as per best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Syncing a sample doc:

```
PUT tester/_doc/1
{
  "news_ID":"123456",
  "news_content":"Apple pencil",
  "keywords":[
    "apple",
    "pencil"
  ],
  "publish_time":"2020-01-03"
}
```

Using a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) w/ a range filter on the top level:

```
GET tester/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "publish_time": {
        "gte": "2020-01-01",
        "lt": "2020-02-01"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_keywords": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "keywords.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use a [filtered aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to aggregate on multiple monthly buckets:

```
GET tester/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "2020-01_2020-02": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "publish_time": {
            "gte": "2020-01-01",
            "lt": "2020-02-01"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_keywords": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "keywords.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "2020-02_2020-03": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "publish_time": {
            "gte": "2020-02-01",
            "lt": "2020-03-01"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_keywords": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "keywords.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention,I've tried elasticsearch terms aggregations,But when the number of keywords is very large ,often more than 10 million, elasticsearch may have performance problems, In the actual project, the keyword is nested type.

Comment: If the mapping is different, please update the question and provide it. Second, if you have too many keywords, you can specify `"size": 10` right under the `field` parameter to limit it. Third, you can try using the `significant_terms` too to investigate the relecance/frequency a bit: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html